# How to compare multiple files in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to find a way to compare multiple files in a directory to files in another directory.
For example - there are 10 files in a directory /home/ansible/properties/ and similar set of files in another directory on remote host like /opt/apps/properties/. I want to compare each of them probably using checksum and even if one of the file is changed then do some task -

Below of my play can compare one file but is there a way to compare all the files or for that matter a directory?

```
- name: Get checksum of my First file
  stat:
    path : "/home/ansible/properties/my.properties"
  register: myfirstfile

- name: Current SHA1
  set_fact:
    1stFilechecksum: "{{ myfirstfile.stat.checksum }}"

- name: Get checksum of my Second File
  stat:
    path : "/opt/aaps/properties/my.properties"
  register: mysecondfile

- name: Current SHA1
  set_fact:
    2ndFilechecksum: "{{ mysecondfile.stat.checksum }}"

- name: Comparing 2 files
  debug:
    msg: "Do Something....."
  when:  1stFilechecksum != 2ndFilechecksum
```

Answer (score 1):

## Test file tree according to your description

... or at least what I understood from it.

```
/tmp/test/a          /tmp/test/b
├── file10.txt       ├── file10.txt
├── file1.txt        ├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt        ├── file2.txt
├── file3.txt        ├── file3.txt
├── file4.txt        ├── file4.txt
├── file5.txt        ├── file5.txt
├── file6.txt        ├── file6.txt
├── file7.txt        ├── file7.txt
├── file8.txt        ├── file8.txt
├── file9.txt        ├── file9.txt
└── toto.txt         └── titi.txt
```

As you can see all files are common except on file in each dir. Those will be be excluded from comparison. For the common files all are different except `file2.txt` and `file5.txt` having the same content.

## The bases used for the solution

- We search for all files in both directories in a loop with [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html). All files in `a` are in `results[0]`, those from `b` in `results[1]`. The `get_checksum` option gathers the info we need.
- In the next task:

  - We loop on files found in `a`.
  - On each iteration, we calculate the corresponding file in `b` by selecting with [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#selectattr) only the list elements having the same `path` name after replacing the dir path. Keeping the first element of the result gives our file. In case the result is empty (not a file in common), we default to an empty object
  - The when clause checks that the files exist (common else we skip) and that they are different (checksum is not equal)
  - [`loop_control`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops) is used to customize the loop varialbe name for readability (i.e. item => file1) and to limit the output of the loop item to something understandable.

## The playbook

```yaml
---
- name: compare files in two dirs
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dir1: /tmp/test/a
    dir2: /tmp/test/b

  tasks:

    - name: "Find all files in {{ dir1 }} and {{ dir2 }}"
      find:
        paths:
          - "{{ item }}"
        get_checksum: true
      register: search_files
      loop:
        - "{{ dir1 }}"
        - "{{ dir2 }}"


    - name: "Compare checksums from {{ dir1 }} to {{ dir2 }}. do something if different"
      vars:
        file2: >-
          {{
            search_files.results[1].files |
            selectattr('path', 'eq', file1.path | replace(dir1, dir2)) |
            list |
            first |
            default({})
          }}
      debug:
        msg: "Files differ. Do something"
      loop: "{{ search_files.results[0].files }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: file1
        label: "Comparing {{ file1.path }} to {{ file2.path | default('N/A') }}"
      when:
        - file2.path is defined
        - file1.checksum != file2.checksum
```

## The result

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [compare files in two dirs] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Find all files in /tmp/test/a and /tmp/test/b] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/b)

TASK [Compare checksums from /tmp/test/a to /tmp/test/b. do something if different] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file1.txt to /tmp/test/b/file1.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file2.txt to /tmp/test/b/file2.txt) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file3.txt to /tmp/test/b/file3.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file4.txt to /tmp/test/b/file4.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file5.txt to /tmp/test/b/file5.txt) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file6.txt to /tmp/test/b/file6.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file7.txt to /tmp/test/b/file7.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file8.txt to /tmp/test/b/file8.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file9.txt to /tmp/test/b/file9.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/file10.txt to /tmp/test/b/file10.txt) => {
    "msg": "Files differ. Do something"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Comparing /tmp/test/a/toto.txt to N/A) 

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```